# Array is not being Instantiated in Constructor

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, global-variables, instantiation

I don't understand why my array is not being instantiated in my constructor.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
public class sandBox {
    int array[];
    int x;

   public void sandBox() {
       array = new int[5];
       x = 0;    
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      sandBox test = new sandBox();

      int arrayTest[];

      arrayTest = new int[10];

      System.out.println(arrayTest.length);

      System.out.print(test.x);
      System.out.print(test.array.length);
   }
}
```

This is what my run time gives me:

> ----jGRASP exec: java sandBox
>
> 10
>
> 0
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at sandBox.main(sandBox.java:21)
>
> ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
>
> ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Naturally the arrayTest.length printed correctly, showing that the error isn't in my syntax.

test.x also printed correctly, showing that my constructor, sandBox(), also 'worked' in that it instantiated x (an int).

But as soon as we need to print test.array.length, I get the null pointer error.  Why?  Wasn't the array instantiated with a length of 5?

Comment: That's not a constructor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `void` from your "constructor" :)

Answer (score 0):

OOF!

As Jorn Vernee pointed out, my constructor wasn't a constructor any more because I added in a void!By getting rid of the void, all problems solved!